# LINQ queries in a generic repository, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I'm setting up a generic repository in my application and I'm having troubles with some LINQ queries.

With a non-generic one, this is what I would do:

```
    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public List<int?> GetGroups()
    {
        List<object> objectGroups = new List<object>();
        List<int?> intGroups = new List<int?>();

        var r = (from n in _objectSet
                 select n.Group_ID).Distinct();

        objectGroups = r.OrderBy(n => n.Value).ToList();

        foreach (object value in objectGroups)
        {
            intGroups.Add((int?)value);
        }

        return intGroups;

    }
```

Since this is a generic one of type **T**, when typing **"n."**, IntelliSense is not listing any options since the type of **n** is not explicitly defined (right?).

So here's what I have so far:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{

    IQueryable<T> Fetch();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(bool activeOnly);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string groupID, bool activeOnly);
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    T First(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    List<int?> GetGroups();
    int Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
    void SaveChanges();
    void SaveChanges(SaveOptions options);
}

public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{



    /// <summary>
    /// The context object for the database
    /// </summary>
    private ObjectContext _context;

    private IEnumerable<T> _previousEntries;
    private string _PKName;

    /// <summary>
    /// The IObjectSet that represents the current entity.
    /// </summary>

    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public DataRepository()
    {

        switch (typeof(T).Name)
        {
            case "CRM_Patient":
                _context = new TheseEntities();
                _PKName = "key_patient";
                break;
            case "CRM_Account":
                _context = new ThoseEntities();
                _PKName = "accountnumber";
                break;
            case "CRM_Supplier":
                _context = new OtherEntities();
                _PKName = "supplierid";
                break;
            default:
                _context = new OtherEntities();
                break;
        }

        _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        _previousEntries = this.GetAll();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all records as an IQueryable
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An IQueryable object containing the results of the query</returns>

    public IQueryable<T> Fetch()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all records as an IEnumberable
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An IEnumberable object containing the results of the query</returns>

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Fetch().AsEnumerable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a record with the specified criteria
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">Criteria to match on</param>
    /// <returns>A collection containing the results of the query</returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate);
    }

    public List<int?> GetGroups()
    {
        List<object> objectGroups = new List<object>();
        List<int?> intGroups = new List<int?>();

        //var r = (from n in _objectSet
        //         select n.GetType().GetProperty("Group_ID").GetValue(n, null)).Distinct();


        var r = Fetch().Select(n => n.GetType().GetProperty("Group_ID").GetValue(n, null)).Distinct();

        objectGroups = r.OrderBy(n => n.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(n, null)).ToList();

        foreach (object value in r)
        {
            intGroups.Add((int?)value);
        }

        return intGroups;

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a single record by the specified criteria (usually the unique identifier)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">Criteria to match on</param>
    /// <returns>A single record that matches the specified criteria</returns>
    public T Single(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Single<T>(predicate);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The first record matching the specified criteria
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">Criteria to match on</param>

    /// <returns>A single record containing the first record matching the specified criteria</returns>
    public T First(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.First<T>(predicate);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the specified entitiy
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity to delete</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"> if <paramref name="entity"/> is null</exception>
    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes records matching the specified criteria
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">Criteria to match on</param>
    public void Delete(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> records = from x in _objectSet.Where<T>(predicate) select x;
        foreach (T record in records)
        {
            _objectSet.DeleteObject(record);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">A boolean value indicating whether or not to dispose managed resources</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_context != null)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
                _context = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Somehow, my reflection tricks seem to be executed in the LINQ statements, which obviously ends up throwing an exception when I assign a value for objectGroups.

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Any ideas ? I really need to preserve the generic nature of the repository. All of the methods where I'm using Reflection are throwing exceptions...

Thanks much.

EDIT: Added most of the Repository's methods and the interface. Some methods might be missing from the class but done so to lighten reading :)

Comment: Here's an interesting article that explains why the Generic Repository might be an Anti-Pattern: http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/03/05/The-Generic-Repository-Is-An-Anti-Pattern.aspx

Comment: Do **all** your entities have a property `Group_ID` and a property `Value`? I'm wondering because you are trying to get those properties on a generic type. Did you consider to have a common base type instead of using reflection? And btw: You really should use `Expression<Func>` as predicates and not just `Func` with LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I think I'll do this from outside the Data Access Layer, once the repository has been typed.


 return _patientRepository.GetAll().Select(n => n.Group_ID).Distinct().ToList()

Comment: You should have a common base type as Slauma indicated.  Then replace `where T : class` with `where T : baseClass` where baseClass is the name of the base class.

Comment: I'm a bit new to these ways of structuring my classes, so for the moment (cause it has to work pretty darn soon) I will pull all the rows into a variable (var r = GetAll()) and then on 'r' I'm able to do some LINQ with reflection. I will surely implement something more solid like this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining the `Value` and `GroupID` properties in an interface, and then making your entities implement this interface and adding this as a generic constraint?

Then your `GetGroups` method will be able to call these properties without reflection.

Comment: I found out that you can use reflection AFTER using AsEnumerable(). Like this: var r = Fetch().AsEnumerable().Select(n => n.GetType().GetProperty("Group_ID").GetValue(n, null)).Distinct(); I guess this is because LINQ is not trying to send reflection stuff to SQL but rather, to a List.

Comment: That's not recommended because reflection is very slow. If you care about performance, try to avoid using it..